# Include aar into aar

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android library distributed in aar format. It weight 300kb. 
I want to create another library and also in aar format, where first library in dependencies. 
But result library weight is 30kb, so obviously it does not not include first library.

I tried to add first library using `flatDir`:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile(name:'mylib-1.0', ext:'aar')
}
```

And publish to mavenLocal using `maven-publish`:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mylib:mylib:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

but still it does not include to result aar.

How to include my first aar to result aar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve it is to distribute the aar with a **maven** repo.

The **aar** file **doesn't contain  the transitive dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.
It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.

Using a **maven repository** you will not have the same issue.
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see there answer to my question there. I want that dependencies will be packed in result aar. How to do this?
About `maven repository` I also did not get it. What should I do? I already use local maven repository and have the same issue.

Comment: @anber As I know there is no automatic way to include an aar inside another one. If you are using a local maven, you should check the pom file.Inside you should have the dependency witht the other lib (aar).