# How to bundle third party dependency into an AAR library

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have an AAR library which sits in Unity Game. Everything was working fine until I used a third-party-library -[USB Serial](https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial) (imported using maven)

Before USB Serial -
AAR size was 80KB

After USB Serial -
AAR size still ~90KB

I then found something is fishy. Upon searching multiple StackOverflow answers, I tried creating local maven, adding transient in implementation and using copyLib task. Below is the link to all solutions i tried:

1. [Sol 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957313/gradle-how-to-include-dependencies-from-repositories-to-output-aar-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Sol 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749728/how-to-specify-dependencies-in-aar-library)
3. [Sol 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522112/include-aar-into-aar)

Can anyone help me with this?

*P.S.- A video will be cool*